# AWS - Using two cloudfront origins to the same S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

#### Is it possible to have a single Cloudfront distribution with two origins that refer to different folders on the same S3 bucket?

I have a simple/small project and to avoid clutter my stack with multiple buckets I'd like to use a single one and have different contents in subfolders, e.g. to use different cache behaviors or serving a single page application from a subfolder and user generated content from the other.

##### But it seems I cannot use the same resource id as an origin id more than once:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution: The parameter origin ID must be unique. (Service: CloudFront, Status Code: 400, Request ID: c0309ded-d a7c-41cf-9efa-3a850856 d075)" (RequestToken: be62d662-15ea-d3d4-1a76-8780f4dda3bb, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

##### Moreover

As a quick workaround I used a second bucket, but this time I get an error about having different origins with the same path:

```
Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: AWS::CloudFront::Distribution: The parameter path pattern must be unique. (Service: CloudFront, Status Code: 400, Request ID: b028a107-1 4be-4f74-a976-f8ecfb58 410e)" (RequestToken: cfa0df4d-5bf6-aceb-7f95-32995ed1d9ea, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)
```

So as a workaround for the workaround I ended setting different buckets and different folders, but it seems so stupid.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [S3 Access Point](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-access-points.html), use its resource policy to restrict access to the required set of folders within the bucket, and then point the CloudFront distribution to the access point.

Comment: the problem is not accessing the bucket, the problem is i can't access it twice with different path

Comment: Could you give the examples of the URLs that you (1) have in your S3 bucket and (2) intend to expose to the client

Comment: I don't think this is relevant, in the cloudformation template i used the bucket resource id as id for both the distribution origins and the bucket regional domain name as the origins domain name. My buckets are not configured for static site hosting since i have a distribution, i don't understand what you mean with `examples of the URLs that you have in your S3 bucket`

Comment: I mean, how can I accurately reproduce the problem you describe, in my account: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example